# can i iterate over the data in a variable in shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, tcsh

So im learning shell script in school right now and i was working on this assignment and was stuck.
Our prof/TA will be testing the answers to this questions by running simple commands like:

`echo <random numbers>| sh question1`

where random numbers can be anything. ie

`echo 7 8| sh question1`
So im not trying to get the answer to the assignment question but i have an idea of how to go about solving the question but, im hitting a bit of a snag out the gate.

I was trying something like this at the begining of my `question1` file:

`VAR1=tr -d [" "]`

my thought process for this is that, i am trying to delete any spaces between the numbers it gives me and putting it in to a variable.
but now im wondering how i can iterate over numbers in the variable

im probably 2-3 weeks into shell scripting and i learned python first so im not even sure if i can even iterate over it. 
But i thought there could be a way where i take the contents of a file, iterate over them and can access one char or integer at a time. 
is this even possible? i spent a lot of time trying to find a solution.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

Does this example help?

```
for i in $* 
    do
    echo $i
done
```

`$*` is a list of the command line args, so running this as `./file.sh a b c` will print a b c

Your input is apparently appearing on a pipe so next do this

```
echo 1 2 3 | xargs ./file.sh
```

`xargs` converts piped values into shell program parameter values

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to [Vorsprung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19089230/1126841) would be to read a single line of input in your script, then use that to set that script's arguments. At the top of your script:

```
read line
set -- $line
```

Then you can use the same for loop:

```
for i in $*; do
    echo $i
done
```

This makes the same assumption as Vorsprung: the input will be a single line of space-separated values. If that assumption is false, I hope your instructors will be more specific about the type of input your script should be able to accept.

Comment: would the answers you two gave (which were great btw) if my prof decided to test my shell script with sh average file1 file2 file3? file 1 and file 2 and file 3 would have only integers in them

Comment: That would change things a lot. Now, your arguments are not the numbers, but file names that you need to read from.

Comment: im guessing its alot harder if i need to be able to do both?